# Use index of an array with obj to remove items or change a flag inside the obj

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am new in react and javascript and I'm trying to create a todo app to learn, everything is working so far except 2 things, the delete and if is completed func. The goal that I want to achieve is to have a button onClick to change the status of completed from false to true and then I will pass a line-through to the particular todo. After this I will have 3 different counters to show the total, completed and incompleted num of todos. The code is as follow:

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
 super();
  this.state = {
    text: '',
    notes: [
      {todo: "test", completed: true},
      {todo: "test2", completed: false}
    ]
  }
}

handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ text: e.target.value })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!this.state.text.length) { return }
  const newTodo = {
    todo: this.state.text,
    completed: false
  }
  const notes = this.state.notes
  notes.push(newTodo)
  this.setState({
    text: '',
    notes: notes
  })
}

handleClick = (index) => {
  const notes = this.state.notes
  notes[index].completed = !notes[index].completed
  this.setState({ notes })
}

handleDelete = (index) => {
  const notes = this.state.notes
  notes.splice(index, 1)
  this.setState({ notes })
}

render() {
  let notes = this.state.notes.map((todo, index) => {
    return <Todo key={index} note={todo} 
    deleteTodo={this.handleDelete} handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
  });
 return (
   <div className="App">
     <div className="notes-wrapper">
     <Header />
     <Form 
       handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
       handleChange={this.handleChange}
       text={this.state.text}
     />
     {notes}
     <Footer notesLength={this.state.notes.length} />
     </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

if I change the array of obj to a simple array like array=[1,2,3] I can do array.splice(index,1) and is working perfectly but in this case something is wrong with the index as I understand. The delete func is working but is deleting a wrong element not the clicked one and also if I do notes[1].completed = !notes[1].completed is working but on both buttons and it will change only the button in the first item. I dont know if is to complicated for a beginner. Thank you!

```
const Todo = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="todo-wrapper">
        <li style={{textDecoration: props.note.completed ? 
        'line-through' : 'none'}}>
            <button className="btn btn-remove" 
             onClick={props.deleteTodo}>Remove</button>
             {props.note.todo}
            <button className="btn btn-status" 
            onClick={props.handleClick}>{props.note.completed ? 
           "Undo" : "Done"}</button>
        </li>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: please write minimal code on so instead of writing article.

Comment: can you show your TodoComponent

Comment: @PanosCool No!! Edit the answer and attach it in a code block, we cannot read it!

Comment: Add your `code` or components to your question please. This is easier to examine for people. Also, I suggest adding an `id` property to your todos. With an `id` you don't hassle with indexes.

Comment: Code add it to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that you need to take care of,

First: You are not passing the index to the functions handleDelete and handleClick from the Todo component.

Second: You should not mutate the original state. Treat it as if its immutable

```
handleClick = (index) => {
  const notes = [...this.state.notes]  // create a copy
  notes[index].completed = !notes[index].completed
  this.setState({ notes })
}

handleDelete = (index) => {

  this.setState(prevState => ({ notes: [...prevState.notes.slice(0, index), ...prevState.notes.slice(index) }))
}

render() {
  let notes = this.state.notes.map((todo, index) => {
    return <Todo key={index} note={todo} index={index}
    deleteTodo={this.handleDelete} handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
  });
 return (
   <div className="App">
     <div className="notes-wrapper">
     <Header />
     <Form 
       handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
       handleChange={this.handleChange}
       text={this.state.text}
     />
     {notes}
     <Footer notesLength={this.state.notes.length} />
     </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
```

And your Todo Component will have

```
<button className="btn btn-remove" onClick={() => props.deleteTodo(props.index)}>Remove</button>
```

and similarly

```
<button className="btn btn-status" onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.index)}>{props.note.completed ? "Undo" : "Done" }</button>
```